# Argparse: print arguments with non-default value

Tags: python, argparse

In the argparse module, is it possible (easily) to print/log arguments that have been changed from default values when running a script? For example,

my_script.py

```
argparse.add_argument("--arg1", default="val1")
argparse.add_argument("--arg2", default="val2")
```

Running:

```
python my_script.py --arg2 newval2
```

Print:

```
Arguments changed:
arg2 : newval2
```

Comment: You can extract default values with [ArgumentParser.get_default(dest)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-default) and then compare them to actual values to find the differences.

Comment: That doesn't tell you if the default value was passed explicitly, or the default had to be supplied after parsing the arguments, though.

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between `myscript.py` and `myscript.py --arg2 val2`?

Comment: `argparse` keeps track of "seen" arguments for its own purposes, but that's a purely internal variable.  It's fairly easy to get the `default` values, and then compare them.  But instead I recommend using the default default `None`, and doing a `if args.arg2 is not None:` to test for new inputs.

Comment: @chepner, in the first case, nothing could be logged.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have parsed your arguments you can, take a look to this script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", dest="c", default=1)

def main():
    options = parser.parse_args()
    print(options.c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you save this code in a script `tmp.py` and then call:

```
$>python3 tmp.py 
$>1
$>python3 tmp.py -c 12
$>12
```

Comment: That only tells you what value was assigned to `options.c`, not whether `-c` was used on the command line or a default value was used.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question

Comment: It's not clear if it's a concern for the OP; I left a comment asking for clarification.